# How to get android animation scale speeds programmatically?

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to get the "**Animator duration scale/speed**" (*from developer options*), in order to set correct animation speed during some processes in my app (*loadings and real time based animations*).

Or, is there any way to Override the speed to default/1x (in case the user setted to 0.5x) to don't write many cases? (*in other words app based animation speed*)

Should I care about this issue, is this a common problem?

Comment: animations have a duration, just change it accordly

Comment: @LucaNicoletti it's like quiz app, the user have 10s to answer but if his animation scale is setted to 0.5x the animation is ending in 5s (it works fine with default, 1x speed). So, animation duration dosen't help me to handle this situation.

Comment: Finally I found this code which helped me get users current animation speed scale.

`Settings.Global.getFloat(getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.ANIMATOR_DURATION_SCALE, 1.0f);`

Comment: might as well answer yourself!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The answer was (just like the comment that I posted under the post):

> Finally, I found this code which helped me get users current animation speed scale.

```
Settings.Global.getFloat(getContentResolver(),
Settings.Global.ANIMATOR_DURATION_SCALE, 1.0f);
```

Comment: Is it possible to disable it for specific Views/animations/Drawable, so that the animation will play in duration scale of `1.0f`, always?

Answer (score -2):

**For SYSTEM apps (hidden class)** `IWindowManager` has a method to get all three types of animation scale:

```
try {
    IWindowManager iwm = IWindowManager.Stub.asInterface(ServiceManager.getService("window"));
    float windowAnimationScale = iwm.getAnimationScale(0);
    float transitionAnimationScale = iwm.getAnimationScale(1);
    float animatorDurationScale = iwm.getAnimationScale(2);
} catch (RemoteException ignore) { }
```

For general apps, if only animator duration scale is needed, simply call this static method:

```
float animatorDurationScale = ValueAnimator.getDurationScale();
```